# Dynamic sheet name in a formula referencing another workbook with same sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a workbook called Source with 2 tabs, January and February. I have another workbook called Destination with the same tabs names: January & February.

I have data in cell A1 on both tabs on the source workbook.

I want cell A1 on the January A1 worksheet of the destination to get the corresponding data from cell A1 if the corresponding tab on the Source workbook.

I know how to do it using the actual tab names but I want to get the tab names dynamically so that when I enter all the needed formulas for other cells, I can then just copy the cells from the January tab to the February tab without having to change the sheet name in the formulas on the February tab (it will automatically know it is February)

Can anyone supply me with the complete dynamic formula using the actual workbook names for just the A1 cell and I can use that as a guide to the other more complicated cell formulas?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you specify the workbook name, you can always use the sheet... even with the same name:

```
='[Source.xlsx]January A1'!A1
```

Just remember that as long as *both* workbooks are not open at the same time, updates are not dynamic... meaning, if you open up "Source", make some changes, then close it... and open up "Destination", it will have old values.  You might be able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to force all values to be updated.